# How to get all categories on opencart admin/catalog/product_form.tpl?

Tags: php, opencart

I'm using opencart 1.5.6 and what I'm trying to do is add a simple select with all the categories and children categories as option on product_form.tpl.

I tried add to the follow code at admin/controler/catalog/product.php:

```
    $this->load->model('catalog/category');

    $results = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories(0);

    foreach ($results as $result) {

        $this->data['categories'][] = array(
            'category_id' => $result['category_id'],
            'name'        => $result['name']
        );
    }
```

and for the view admin/view/catalog/product_form.tpl:

```
<tr>
              <td>Categories</td>
              <td><select>
                      <option value="">All Categories</option>
                      <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $category['name']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></option>
                      <?php } ?>
                  </select>
              </td>
          </tr>
```

but it's not working. It returns nothing.

I wish someone could help me and tell me what I'm missing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think Your approach is good but one small mistake - the method `getCategories()` in administration part does not receive the `$parent_id` paramaters, but `array $data` parameter (for sorting and filtering possibilities). So if You want to load the categories in Your `product` controller, You can proceed like this (I am reusing Your code):

```
$this->load->model('catalog/category');

$this->data['categories'] = array();

foreach ($this->model_catalog_category->getCategories(array()) as $category) {
    $this->data['categories'][] = array(
        'category_id' => $category['category_id'],
        'name'        => $category['name']
    );
}
```

And in Your template:

```
      <?php if($categories) { ?>
      <tr>
          <td>Categories</td>
          <td><select>
                  <option value="">All Categories</option>
                  <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $category['category_id']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></option>
                  <?php } ?>
              </select>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <?php } ?>
```

I think this is almost the same as what You had, do not understand why it didn't work for You...

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to get a complete list of categories is to call the database directly, such as

```
$result = $this->db->query("
    SELECT
        `category_id`,
        `name`
    FROM
        `" . DB_PREFIX. "category_description`
    WHERE
        `language_id` = '" . (int) $this->config->get('config_language_id')  . "'
");
```

However these will not show the parent categories, or be in any particular order. To do that you would need to run a recursive lookup of `$this->model_catalog_category->getCategories(0);` changing the `0` to the looped `category_id` to find it's children, and their children

Comment: Sorry for my noobness but I don't get it. Should I call it from the controller?

Comment: I don't think calling a `SQL` queries directly from controller is a good way. And I hate this approach being seen in almost every third party extension (even when using vQmod). This approach totally breaks the MVC pattern and should be avoided. Don't be that lazy and write that method into a model or create a new model for that...